# How Can I Put Text On the Right Top Corner

Tags: html, css

I need help putting text on the right top corner!

I search on Google, StackOverflow and on youtube

```
<html>
    <a href=login.html>LogIn</a>
</html>
```

I'm expecting I can put that login text on the right top corner!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To position the link in the top right corner of the viewport, there are several approaches.

### Fixed Positioning

```css
a {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<a href=login.html>LogIn</a>
```

### Absolute Positioning

```css
a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<a href=login.html>LogIn</a>
```

### CSS Grid (overkill, yes)

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  justify-items: end;
}
```

```html
<a href=login.html>LogIn</a>
```

### Flexbox

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<a href=login.html>LogIn</a>
```

### Table Positioning

```css
a {
  display: table;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<a href=login.html>LogIn</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use css?

```css
a#login {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<a id="login" href=login.html>LogIn</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
a{
  position:fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<html><a href=login.html>LogIn</a></html>
```

```html
<html><div style="text-align:right"><a href=login.html>LogIn</a></div></html>
```